# MapContainer show only on click/touch

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use naive map.

I have places a MapContainer insider a Form Component but the From shows blank without the map inside it, on the simulator. When I click on the viewport the map shows as long as the mouse button remains down. When I release it disappear again.

Is it a real problem or is it a misfunction of the simulator? If it is a real problem what am I doing wrong?

below is the class I am using:

```
package com.mainsys.zappeion;

import com.codename1.googlemaps.MapContainer;
import com.codename1.maps.Coord;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;

/**
 *
 * @author Christoforos
 */
public class ZappeionMap extends com.codename1.ui.Form {
     private Form current;

      public ZappeionMap() {
        super("Ζάππειον", new BorderLayout());

    }

     @Override
    public void show() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer();
        this.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);
        cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(41.889, -87.622));
        super.show();
    }

}
```

/********** Implementing Shai's answer ******************/

I changed my code to what Shai suggested show my class now is:

```
package com.mainsys.zappeion;

import com.codename1.googlemaps.MapContainer;
import com.codename1.location.Location;
import com.codename1.location.LocationManager;
import com.codename1.maps.Coord;
import com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent;
import com.codename1.ui.FontImage;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.Style;

/**
 *
 * @author Christoforos
 */
public class ZappeionMap extends com.codename1.ui.Form {
     private Form current;
private static final String HTML_API_KEY = "AIzaSyDHlFJK561bQVs0AyBm1M5xWS_YCHNuPfc";
      public ZappeionMap() {
        super("Ζάππειον", new BorderLayout());
        final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer( HTML_API_KEY );
        this.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);
        cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(41.889, -87.622));
    }      
}
```

It still having the same problem. The screen is blank. The map only shown when I click on the screen.

I also noticed something else. On the debuger I get the message:

```
WARNING: Apple will no longer accept http URL connections from applications you tried to connect to http://tile.openstreetmap.org/4/2/9.png to learn more check out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html
```

Why is it trying to connect to http://tile.openstreetmao.org. It is supposed to work with google maps not with openstreet maps.

One more information, maybe it is worh something. I test it on real device. The screen is still blink but when I touch the screen it does not show anythink, in contrast with the simulater that when I click on the screen the map appears.

I am using netbeans 8.2 on centos 7

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you Christoforos.

Comment: You constructed the map without the JavaScript key to access google maps. I suggest reviewing the steps here over again: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-improved-native-google-maps.html

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I changed my code as you can see it in my last edit. I construct the map using the api key. Still the same. I see the map only when I click on it.

Comment: If you constructed the map that way and are still getting those messages it means you missed a step in the configuration as open street map shouldn't occur. You probably got an exception or printout higher than that in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you overriding the show method of form and don't construct the UI n the constructor?

It looks like you copied some code from the lifecycle class and mixed it with a form subclass e.g. the current variable.

This is closer to correct:

```
public class ZappeionMap extends com.codename1.ui.Form {
     private Form current;

     public ZappeionMap() {
        super("Ζάππειον", new BorderLayout());
        final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer();
        this.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);
        cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(41.889, -87.622));
     }

}
```

Comment: sorry this did not worked. You can see my edit on the question.